# How to write big files with BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, binarywriter

I have some program which write a large binary files. And I meet the problem: sometimes my programm crash on file writing without throwing any error (block catch don't execute. I write some test console application to find and fix this problem. Somthing like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        string fileName = @"D:\Users\nimci\Desktop\buf\"+j+".bin";
        using (var output =
            new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
            {
                output.Write(i);
                //if(i%1000==0)   Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i have such results: Some files have 0 size. For example the files with numbers 8, 10, 15, 17,...

On my home (less powerfull) computer all the files have been written correctly, byt on my work computer some of them have 0 size. If I uncomment Thread.Sleep(1); (or slow my program in other way) all the files correct on my work computer too, but such "fix" don't work on my server computer. 
Can anybody explain what the error occured and how can I fix it?
I try to use try-cath-finally instead using, but catch block don't catch this error.

Comment: it should not matter, but can you confirm that output.Close() as the last line of your using block does not help?

Comment: Cannot replicate. Well `using` should take care of closing and disposing, so I write this as a comment but I will try to insert a `output.Flush();` after the internal loop

Comment: output.Flush(); didn't help. Still 0 size files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Flush:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)         
        {         
            output.Write(i);         
            //if(i%1000==0)   Thread.Sleep(1);         
        }  
        output.Flush();
```

Comment: It's definitely worth nothing that ReadAllBytes and WriteAllBytes behave poorly with big files *especially* on a network.

Comment: In my program I need to save array in the binary file. The binary writer have write(int) method. This method attend bites from int value and write they to stream.  Byt why I attend the 0 size files?

Comment: @hometoast - Yes, I realized that as well.

Comment: output.Flush(); didn't help. Still 0 size files.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, but only after I ran the test once.  Some of the files are being reported as 0 byte files, but in reality, all the data is present.